# Unity 3D C# how to limit camera angle?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to figure this out for the past few hours and I figure there must be something off about my code making this extra difficult. I'm trying to make a first-person controller with the new input system and stop the camera from going 360 degrees vertically. I have the horizontal rotation applied to the player and the vertical rotation applied to a camera that is a child of said player. This is what I got sorry if it's a CF.

I've Tried Mathf.clamp and euler angles but I can't seem to get anything to work.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class FirstPersonController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AICOde PlayerControls;

    Vector2 moveDirection = Vector2.zero;

    public Vector3 jumpForce;

    float hlookDirection;

    float vlookDirection;

    public float isJumping;

    public InputAction move;

    public InputAction jump;

    public InputAction look;

    public Rigidbody rb;

    public bool isOnGround;

    public float moveSpeed;

    public float sensitivity;

    public Camera playerCamera;

    public Quaternion cameraRotation;


    private void Awake()
    {
    
        PlayerControls = new AICOde();
    }
    private void Start()
    {
        playerCamera = gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Camera>();
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }
 
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        jump = PlayerControls.Player.Jump;
        move = PlayerControls.Player.Move;
        look = PlayerControls.Player.Look;
        move.Enable();
        jump.Enable();
        look.Enable();
    }
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        move.Disable();
        jump.Disable();
        look.Disable();
    }
     private void Update()
    {
        

        cameraRotation = playerCamera.transform.rotation;
        hlookDirection = look.ReadValue<Vector2>().x;
        vlookDirection = look.ReadValue<Vector2>().y;
        moveDirection = move.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        isJumping = jump.ReadValue<float>();
        
       
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //MOVE PLAYER
        rb.velocity = transform.TransformDirection (new Vector3(moveDirection.x * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y, moveDirection.y * moveSpeed));

        //ROTATE PLAYER WITH MOUSE
        gameObject.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, hlookDirection * sensitivity * Time.deltaTime );

        //ROTATE CAMERA WITH MOUSE
       

       playerCamera.transform.Rotate(Vector3.left,vlookDirection * sensitivity * Time.deltaTime);
        
        
        
        //JUMP
        if (isJumping > 0 && isOnGround == true)
        {

            
            rb.AddForce(jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }

        if (isJumping > 0)
        {
            isOnGround = false;
            
        }
        if (isOnGround)
        {
            moveSpeed = 5f;
        }
        else
        {
            moveSpeed = 4f;
        }


    }

   //MAKE SURE PLAYER IS ON GROUND BEFORE JUMPING
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if(collision.collider.CompareTag("Ground"))
        {
            
            isOnGround = true;
        }
        else 
        {
            isOnGround = false;
        }
    }

    
    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could track how much you have rotated up or down already. Define a `float currentUpDownAngle = 0f;` in your `FirstPersonController`. Then, instead of

```
//ROTATE CAMERA WITH MOUSE
playerCamera.transform.Rotate(Vector3.left,vlookDirection * sensitivity * Time.deltaTime);
```

you do

```
//ROTATE CAMERA WITH MOUSE

float MAX_UPDOWN_ANGLE = 60f;  // define a limit (maybe somewhere else)
float change = vlookDirection * sensitivity * Time.deltaTime; // get the wanted change

// check if the change would exceed the maximum, we do it for both directions at once
// if you want another minimum angle, divide the code in two parts
if (Mathf.Abs(currentUpDownAngle + change) > MAX_UPDOWN_ANGLE) { // do we exceed?
    float limit = Mathf.Sign(change) * MAX_UPDOWN_ANGLE; // get up or down limit
    change = limit - currentUpDownAngle;  // get the rest to limit
    currentUpDownAngle = limit;  // snap to the limit
}
else {
    currentUpDownAngle += change;  // no limit hit, free change
}
// rotates at most to the limit
playerCamera.transform.Rotate(Vector3.left, change);
```